# How to show hierarchical data structure with RecycleView?

Tags: android, ios, uitableview, android-recyclerview

In iOS if your datastructure has **two level**, 'sections', 'rows' then `UITableView` is good for presenting data. It has two delegate method:

```
numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int    
tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

First method ask for number of sections, second one how many row in a certain section exist.

Does this approach exist in Android?

[image]

Comment: Many of [the available libraries that augment `RecyclerView`](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/199) offer headers/sections or a tree-style "expandable" system.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android) is what you are looking for. 
**cons**: You will need to manage headers title by yourself. 
**pros**: Solution doesn't require additional library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the library [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) to group your data into sections.

First create a Section class:

```
class MySection extends StatelessSection {

    String title;
    List<String> list;

    public MySection(String title, List<String> list) {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header, footer and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.section_item);

        this.title = title;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return list.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(list.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new SimpleHeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        MyHeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (MyHeaderViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your header view here
        headerHolder.tvItem.setText(title);
    }
}
```

Then you set up the RecyclerView with your Sections:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

// Create your sections with the list of data for each year
MySection section1 = new MySection("A", firstDataList);
MySection section2 = new MySection("B", secondDataList);

// Add your Sections to the adapter
sectionAdapter.addSection(section1);
sectionAdapter.addSection(section2);

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

Comment: This is a really bad library that hardcode the inflate of the views, making do things like databinding virtually impossible. And don't exactly simplify things.

Answer (score 2):

RecyclerView.Adapter supports multiple view types out of the box. It's up to you which item type you want to display at any particular position. You can easily use it to create sections, for example if you define two item types TYPE_HEADER and TYPE_ITEM:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isHeader(position)) {
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    } else {
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }
}
```

Then, you can use `onCreateViewHolder` to inflate proper layouts and `onBindViewHolder` to make use of it.

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        View v = ... ; // inflate here
        return new HeaderViewHolder(v);
    } else {
        View v = ... ; // inflate here
        return new ItemViewHolder(v);
    }    
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {
        // handle header
    } else if (holder instanceof ItemViewHolder {
        // handle item
    }
}
```

You can use data structure of your choice. I prefer using tree-like structures of my own implementation or just plain ArrayList and instanceof to detect if item is header or content.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own adapter for recycleview that handles 2 (or more) types of listitems, add them to a list (in the way you want) and then pass it to adapter.